# Implement OAuth provider in Rails for use with a single client application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, single-sign-on

I'm working on building a closed community forum for members of an existing site I also built. I'd like to allow members to sign in to the new forum using their existing accounts on the main application. The forum will be on a different domain from the main site.

This will be my first time using OAuth. Most information on the web about  it seems to skew heavily toward allowing users to sign in with Twitter/Facebook/etc accounts, and there's very little information that seems pertinent to what I'm working on.

I'd like to create an OAuth provider in the original web app and a OAuth client in the new app I'm building. No other providers will be used, and no other client sites will be authenticating off this main site. Additionally, I need to avoid any sort of "authorize this web site" intermediary step for my users.

The main site is Rails 4 with Devise, and the new site is Rails 5. I'd like to stick with Devise on the new site as well, which I understand can function as an OAuth client. Doorkeeper seems like it could be overkill for my exceedingly simple needs, but most other information I've found is years out of date, so I don't want to invest time pursuing an implementation that won't work or is not the current best approach.

What is currently the best way to handle this kind of single-client, single-provider setup?

Comment: Hm. Are you *sure* you want to use OAuth for this? It's a lot of lifting for the scenario you outline.

Comment: No necessarily, no. Is there a better option for allowing users to sign in to a second domain using their existing accounts on a different domain? To the best of my knowledge, OAuth is how you do this, but I'd be happy to learn of other options!

Comment: Both applications are yours, yes? Why not just create a registration API on the main application where you send over (encrypted) log in credentials from the second application and then check those credentials against the database on the main application? Then, you can return an appropriate response and handle it in your second application.

Comment: A valid idea, for sure. Unfortunately the reality is that I have no experience (also time, man hours constraints) creating a system like this and so have a strong preference for something where I can drop in a gem and go (not that it's ever really _that_ simple but you know what I mean). OAuth seems to fit the bill, apart from the complexity and overall weight (as you note).

Comment: I hear you. Having implemented both, my personal experience has been that the OAuth path is a much longer and harder one. But, that's just one person's experience.